# Springboot app ResponseBodyAdvice Not triggered

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to update an audit entry using the response body advice but as far as I can tell it never gets executed.  I see the bean in the logs:

```
{"timestamp":"2018-08-21T15:48:08.349Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main",
"logger":"org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter",
"message":"Detected ResponseBodyAdvice bean in responseAuditAdvice","context":"default"}
```

My controller method looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/stage", consumes = {
    "application/json"
}, produces = {
    "application/json"
})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> stage(@Valid @RequestBody StagingDto stagingDto,
                               @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT) String userAgent,
                               BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

I have a RequestAuditAdvice that extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter and it is working fine.  Also if the error flow occurs I see the exception advice executing as well.  it is only the response advice that is failing to trigger.  Any suggestions?

here is the advice bean:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Inject)
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResponseAuditAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
private final RequestService requestService;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class selectedConverterType,
                              ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
         log.info("Updating audit for response.");
         String ip = new String (request.getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getAddress());
         requestService.auditResponse(ip, 200);
         return body;
    }
}
```